# real analyticity, Fourier coefficients

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

> **Question.** Suppose $f$ is periodic in $[0,2\pi]$. What conditions on the Fourier coefficients of $f$ would guarantee real analyticity of $f$? Please provide me with a reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ periodic by $2\pi$ is real analytic if and only if it extends holomorphically to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ |\Im z|<c\}$ for some $c>0$, because the interval $[0,2\pi]$ is compact. The latter condition is easily seen to be equivalent to the exponential decay of the Fourier coefficients: $a_n\ll e^{-c|n|}$ for come $c>0$. (Necessity of this condition follows from Cauchy's theorem about integrals of holomorphic functions. Sufficiency of the condition follows from Morera's theorem and Cauchy's theorem about the analyticity of holomorphic functions.)

Comment: For a reference (since OP asked for one): _An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis_ by Y. Katznelson, 3rd edition, exercise 4 from section I.4

Comment: @WillieWong: Thank you. I did not know a reference from the top of my head, so I just thought it over.

Comment: Neither did I. After seeing your answer I had to go to my book case and look around a bit. I was convinced I've seen that condition before somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

The condition is $|c_n|\le A e^{-B|n|}$ for some positive constants $A,B$ and all $n$. This is not difficult to prove directly (a reference might be exercise I.4.4 in Katznelson's Introduction to Harmonic Analysis, but it is given as an exercise...).

Comment: oh I was writing at the same time as GH but he was faster :)